# How do I add a class to a row based on the value of a field in that row?

Tags: 7, views, theming

I have a view with a page display showing a list of events. I'd like to add a class to the rows of those events that are in the past.

The problem I have is that views-view-list.tpl.php doesn't have access to the values of fields within the rows.

And I can use views-view-fields.tpl.php to check the date field of one row, and wrap each field in that row with a div or span based on whether or not the date field is in the past.

I just can't figure out how to use the value of a field within a row to wrap the whole row in something with a class.

Answer (score 7):

The following will add the class 'hello' to the li tag. I used a view with machine name 'dates' and a display name of 'page'. The time field is the node created time. You can just install Devel and uncomment the dpm($vars) statement to get what you need. I also left the conditional logic up to you.

Put this in your theme's template.php file:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_views_view_list(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['view']->name == 'dates' && $vars['view']->current_display == "page") {
    // dpm($vars); //uncomment to see variables
    foreach($vars['view']->result as $key => $value){
      $timestamp = $value->node_created;
      if ($timestamp) { // add whatever conditional logic you need here
        $vars['classes_array'][$key] .= ' hello'; // note the space in front of class
      }
    }
  }
}
```

An **alternative method** is as follows:

Put this in your theme's template.php file:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['view']->name == 'dates' && $vars['view']->current_display == "page") {
    $timestamp = $vars['row']->node_created;
    if ($timestamp < strtotime('now')) {
      $vars['classes_array'][] = 'bye';
    }
  }
}
```

and use this views-view-fields--VIEWNAME.tpl.php file:

```
<div class="<?php print $classes;?>">
<?php foreach ($fields as $id => $field): ?>
  <?php if (!empty($field->separator)): ?>
    <?php print $field->separator; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php print $field->wrapper_prefix; ?>
  <?php print $field->label_html; ?>
  <?php print $field->content; ?>
  <?php print $field->wrapper_suffix; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: OMG OMG OMG THIS TOTALLY WORKED (I used the first chunk of code in my template.php). Thank you SO. MUCH.

Comment: Is there a way to do this by only using the template file?

Comment: You will have to move the logic that is in the preprocess function into the beginning of the template, and add the class to the $classes variable (not the classes_array variable). The variables that in the preprocess function is accessed under $vars will have been flattened so that in the template file you can access them directly, ie $vars['view'] will become $view.

Comment: couldn't user $vars['classes_array'][$key] for table style because of Notice: Undefined offset: 2 error where 2 is the found key. Is this only works for non-table styles