# Adding Class to views row if View style is Unformatted list / Content

Tags: views, theming

I need to add a CSS class to a views row depending on a field. So far this is easy going if I use Fields as Content (add class via replacement patterns then).

But I find it far more difficult to do this when using Row style "Content" and a custom view mode (e. g. Teaser).

I found the following code to work for me if I use Row style "Content":

```
function mytheme_preprocess_views_view_unformatted(&$vars) {
foreach($vars['view']->result as $rkey => $rval)
{
    $node = node_load($rval->nid);
    if(isset($node->field_breite) && !(empty($node->field_breite)))
    {
        $vars['classes_array'][$rkey] .= $vars['classes_array'][$rkey] . " " . $node->field_breite[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
    }
}
```

}

**I like to ask if this is a suitable approach or am I maybe wasting resources by loading each node and can I grab the node data easier somewhere else?**

PS: It is not a option for me here to use Fields in the View as content because I want to use different content types in the view with different fields.

Settings:
[image]

Comment: Can you Tell my what you want to do, you just want add class to your views row?

Comment: Yes, just want to add a class to the view, but based on a field value in the related node.

Comment: I don't understand, you want add a class of fields in row equal to specified value? and you want only use unformatted in Row Style Format?

Comment: Yes, I want to add the value of a field as a class to the views row and I am using the Views Row Style "Content". Including a screenshot of the settings.

Comment: what is the problem of you code? It seems work correctly

Comment: IMHO this is not a duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/127856, because I am asking for a view where MYTHEME_preprocess_views_view_list and MYTHEME_preprocess_views_view_fields are not called because of the View Settings (see question) and therefore the answers from http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/127856 are not helpful here

Comment: Please review edit your question,it seems what you want is exactly as another question, add  data field value as a class to view result row.

Comment: It is different because I do not have views-view-list nor views-view-fields because of my view settings

Comment: You said `I found the following code to work for me if I use Row style "Content"` and in your snapshot it is Content with "Teaser" , did you say anything about teaser in your question? If you want we can help you please edit question with better details about  your problem.tnx

Comment: I have added the "Teaser" information in the text now, but basically it is not about a specific view mode but about any view mode (Teaser, Full Content, Custom Mode) and how to add the class. And I am only asking if there might be a better way (without loading each node) to get the results that my code delivers.

Answer (score 1):

You can try do this later in process or template, when the `$vars['rows']` is flattened. You can pull all instances of `field_breite` out of the flattened row and put them into the classes of the row. For this the `field_breite` has to be in the custom view mode of course. This would be not so nice for coding, but much faster.

I would code it like this in `mytheme_process_views_view(&$vars)`, but I'm sure you need some debugging:

Go row by row in $vars['rows']. Search the complete field with preg_match() by using the html tags of the field and set parenthesis in the regular expression to get the field value in $matches[1]. Add the field value in $matches[1] to $vars['classes_array'][$id] to set the row class. Cut the complete field out of the row with str_replace() by using $matches[0] from the first search and an empty string.

Comment: You mean by search and replace the html output and I would need the field in the view mode and hide it by CSS?

Comment: No, my idea was to remove the field from the row, after using it to extract the row class. See my edited answer.

Comment: as far as I can see $vars['rows'] is one big HTML string. While the search and replace might be feasible it will not work to put the class to var['classes'] because these are the classes for the view and not for the row.

Comment: You are right, the row classes are in `$classes_array[$id]`. The coding is not the easiest, but the fastest way that came into my mind. Otherwise your original code is fine, but 10 or 100 times slower.

Comment: Ok, but it seems $classes_array[$id] also contains the view classes and not the row classes. Thanks for your input, seems that there is no very easy solution to that, so maybe I leave it with my code since I am not having that much content in this view.