# Add class on row by modifying view.tpl.php file

Tags: 7, views, theming

I am trying to add some classes on the specific row in one of my view table. I have tried to use MYTHEME_preprocess_views_view_table, but failed. Nothing changed on my page.(Here is my previous question link:[How to add css class to specific rows base on fields in order commerce view page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/221066/how-to-add-css-class-to-specific-rows-base-on-fields-in-order-commerce-view-page), if you have any idea about this, I am interested in hearing from you). So I decided to create a new view.tpl.php file to display them. However, nothing showed on my page again.

Here is a screenshot includes: 1.my view theme detector 2.my code 3.result on Chrome
[image]

I can find my file being used by my view, however, I don't see any changes on my page. Does anyone know what mistake I have made? Or any idea about how to add class on specific row.

**Update:**

I have already cleared the cache several times.

**Finally:**
Normally, Chris Happy's answer should work. But there might be some problem with my website, so we figured it out my problem by using JQuery. Thank you for @Chris Happy's help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it out, and it didn't work for me....until I cleared the cache!

Just go to yoursite.com/admin/config/development/performance/ and click "clear all caches".

**Update**: since clearing the cache didn't work, check if you are editing the right file: delete all the code in the tpl.php file.

- If the view disappears, you are editing the right file.
- If it still shows, close your editor window and select the file again.

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to point out this. I have already cleared my caches for several time.

Comment: Have you made sure that you were editing the correct file? I have double checked it and I can't reproduce. Updated answer for things to check

Comment: Here are my steps: First, I go the page which displays my view, then I click "edit view" on that page. Now, I was directed to view edit page. All the information I used are from this page. Therefore, I thought I was editing the right file. But it's still not working...

Comment: I meant your views-view-table--page-1.tpl.php file. Please erase all the code, flush the cache, and tell me what happens to your view.

Comment: Okay...Hmm... Nothing happened. The view is still displayed.

Comment: Okay, double check that your views-view-table--page-1.tpl.php file is still showing up in the theme registry. If it still shows, close your code editor for that file and reopen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49261/discussion-between-chris-happy-and-jmu).

Comment: Sorry that I had to leave yesterday. I tried when I came back, but the problem is still there. Would you mind discuss more whenever you have time today?

Comment: Just to add my two cents here. When I had a similar issue with changes not showing up I put this line `$conf['theme_debug'] = TRUE;` in my settings.php file. Enabling theme debug generates extra markup indicating which file is used. That helped me a lot.